# smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp

In one of my projects I have to create python application to send email reports from local machine, using external smtp infrastructure.

I am using python 2.7.13 (latest at the moment) on local windows computer for testing and aws EC2 windows instance for production (same python version).

The code is: (simplified version)

```
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.host.com', 587)
s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.ehlo()
s.login('email@domain.com', 'password');
s.sendmail(from_to, from_to, m.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Everything works great on local computer, but while running on amazon ec2, I'm getting:

```
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'email@domain.com': (450, '4.7.1 <MY-INSATNCE-ID.aws-region.compute.internal>: Helo command rejected: Host not found')}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is (was) that EC2 instance has configured local FQDN. It was bound to internal domain name system, therfore remote smtp server was not able to resolve and confirm it.

On the other hand, local computer used *unknown* FQDN passing only its local ip, which was ok for smtp server. I'm not sure if it is not a security issue.

The problem may be solved by adding `local_hostname` parameter to `SMTP` constructor.

Square brackets are obligatory.

```
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.host.com', 587)
```

to

```
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.host.com', 587, '[127.0.0.1]')
```